# Deploying SFMC changes to next higher org in Salesforce Marketing

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit, sfmcadmin

I'm new to SFMC and started learning and exploring the platform. As I don't have any hands-on in the platform so I wanted to check like in Salesforce we have different orgs and we can deploy changes from one org to another by using SFDX or change set and other ways. But in case of SFMC how do we deploy our changes to next higher org. For ex : the Email templates that we created or the Ampscript that we developed, how can we deploy these changes to production?

I would really appreciate if there is any tutorial on SFMC deployment where we can learn how SFMC deployment works with Salesforce.

Comment: Marketing Cloud only has production orgs and no deployment process. To move stuff between business units, you can use Package Manager

Comment: Thanks @zuzannamj. Is there any documentation or video on how to use Business units and package manager for moving stuffs?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_marketing_cloud_package_manager.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the detailed demo for using the package manager in SFMC.
https://trailblazercommunitygroups.com/events/details/salesforce-salesforce-marketer-group-pardot-singapore-singapore-presents-episode-23-sfmc-bootcamp-assets-package-manager/

Comment: Thanks Pankaj for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

SFMC package manager allow you to export a list of assets (journeys, automations, data extensions, cloud pages, emails) from one business unit into zip file, then you can switch to the target business unit to import those assets.

There are a few things to note here:

1. Newly imported assets will be appended with timestamps in the names, in some scenarios if you are referencing them by name, e.g. Ampscript reference DE by name, SQL query activity reference DE by name. You will need to manually fix the DE name once imported, or update to new names in Ampscript or Query.
2. Package Manager cannot replicate synchronised CRM objects in Contact Builder, so if you have multi-org CRM > SFMC connectors, if you synchronise CRM objects in one Business Unit as synchronised data extensions, you have to manually synchronise those objects in target business unit. Also synchronised data extensions will have different names, so you need to fix your queries if you have references to synchronised data extensions in query. e.g. DE may be called Contact_Salesforce in one business unit, and Contact_Salesforce_1 in another business unit. You are connecting to different CRM orgs in multi-org setup.
3. If you have using single-org connector, you should always setup CRM>SFMC connector in your parent Business Unit, then create automation and queries to segment data into shared data extensions for different Business Units, also setup business unit folder access for your shared data extensions

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Also, Just to ensure that nobody accidentally creates anything directly in PROD Business unit. So, is there a way to make PROD specific Business unit secure ?

Comment: @sfdc07 you can configure user roles and permissions to hide some components from that user, you can also configure business unit access, for example some user may only have access to certain BUs. in a parent > children BUs structure, you can setup single CRM connector at parent BU and copy data into child BU in parent BU automation into shared DEs that only visible to users have access to specific BUs